# How does one create a "product-favored reaction equilibrium"?

Tags: equilibrium

> For the following reaction equilibrium, which of the following actions
>   would not only temporarily increase the yield of product, but also
>   result in a more product-favored reaction equilibrium overall (i.e.,
>   increase the Keq)?
>
> $\ce{2A(s) + 3B(g) ↔ A2B3(g)}$
>
> ΔH = −50 kJ/mol
>
> (1)  compressing (decreasing the volume of) the reaction vessel and
>   increasing the temperature
>
> *Correct answer: (2)  compressing (decreasing the volume of) the
>   reaction vessel and decreasing the temperature*
>
> (3)  expanding (increasing the volume of) the reaction vessel and
>   increasing the temperature
>
> (4)  expanding (increasing the volume of) the reaction vessel and
>   decreasing the temperature
>
> **Wrong answer I'm curious about: (5)  increasing the amount of A(s)
>   and decreasing the temperature**

I know that increasing the amount of A(s) will not affect the equilibrium because it is a solid and solids exist at a constant concentration in general, so we ignore them in equilibrium constants.

I think that there are actually two parts to this question:

> For the following reaction equilibrium, which of the following actions
>   would not only **temporarily increase the yield of product**, but also
>   result in a more product-favored reaction equilibrium overall (i.e.,
>   **increase the Keq**)?

To temporarily increase the yield, we must increase the pressure/decrease the volume of the container. But to actually change the K so that it is increased, we must change the temperature. Since this reaction is exothermic, decreasing the temperature will do the trick.

Is my reasoning valid?

Comment: Consider the change in free energy $\Delta G =\Delta H -T\Delta S$. As A is a solid as long as it is in excess, over its stoichiometric amount, its saturated vapour pressure is constant at constant T.